# Program to Find Perfect Cube By Factorization

Tags: javascript, c, authentication

I just want some help for an Program in C /JS to find perfect Cube Using Following Factorization Method  Any help would be appricated

- 3 * 3 * 3
- 3 * 3 * 3
- 3 * 3 * 3

Code

```
var num=19683;
   var arr=[];
   for(i=2;i<num;i++){
  if(num%i==0){
     arr.push(i);
  }
}
```

C-Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num=19683;
    int a[20];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=2;i<num;i++){
    if(num%i==0){
       a[j]=i;
        j++;

    }

    }
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
    printf(" %i", a[i]);
    }
}
```

getting Result :as

> 1,3,9,27,81,243,729,2187,6561

Comment: Please chose a language

Comment: you seem to have coded in js.. so why tag C?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY then condition will be false. No problem with that

Comment: Hello ,
I just needed help in logic this is sample code i have written which i executed on browser If you can help with this then would be helpful

Comment: @Mr_Perfect not in C.

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: @SiddharthJain you don`t understand that code, and you want, that anybody explain it?

Comment: Why can't you do it `i*i*i === num`?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich Actually i am going through this logic since morning not able to find specific with factorization method, this for above code i want to have result like factors which are not again divided like for this 3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3

Comment: i don`t understand what are you want)

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I tried with that but getting result as 27 as its a cube of 27 but for calculating whether 19683 is a perfect cube or not i need factors in normalize group like for 27 it is 3*3*3

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich I just want to have program for whether entered number is perfect cube or not

Answer (score 1):

Although the desired result is unclear,
Is this something like that?

```js
var num=1881365963625;
var arr=[];
var find = "yes";
for(var i = 2; i < num; i++){
  var count = 0;
  while(num % i==0){
     num /= i;
     ++count;
  }
  if(count % 3 != 0){
     find = "no";
     break;
  } else if(count != 0){
     arr.push([i, count]);
  }
}
console.log(find);
if(find == "yes")
  console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested fast C-solution:

```
int isPerfectCube(long int num){
    long int x = pow(num, 1.0/3) + 0.5;
    return (x*x*x == num);
}
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that it relies on floating point arithmetics. The advantage is that it is fast (untested but should be true) and easy to implement, and passes on the heavy work to `pow()` which probably handles this iteratively.

The minimum requirement for accuracy of `pow(num, 1.0/3)` is that it's at least closer to the correct integer than to any other integer when `num` is in fact a perfect cube. Otherwise the algorithm will fail (that's why floating point precision is a disadvantage to these kind of problems). The `+ 0.5` will make sure to round it to the nearest integer upon truncation from `double` to `int`. If you want to use this solution you may want to check for which range of numbers `pow()` is accurate enough.

A safer and perhaps even faster solution would probably involve making some iterative algorithm yourself. That's what I would try to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the entered number is perfect cube or not

```
 var num = 19683, c=0;
    for(var i=1; i<=num; i++){
      if((num%i===0)&&(i*i*i === num)){
        c = c+1;
      }
    }
    if(c > 0) {
     console.log('Yes')
    } else console.log('No');
```

May be this may take less time

```
var num = 100000000, c=0, arr=[];
for(var i=1; i<(num/2)+1; i++){
  if(num%i===0){

    arr.push(i);
  }
}
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
   var x = arr[i];
   if(x*x*x === num) c = c+1;
}
if(c > 0) {
 console.log('Yes')
} else console.log('No')
```

Comment: Is it is feasible for any number like 86821047424 whether this is feasible
above will work good for 10000000 till this number but after that is not working